# How to make this HTML snippet Responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the folowing html, [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgfUT/4/)
**Update**: Note, I am also using the Jquery Mobile in the page,

```
        <div class="control my-control">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>Title:</div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>Lyrics:    </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="lyric-content"></div>
                </div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snowish/72x72/actions/gtk-media-play-ltr.png"></div>
    </div>​
```

This is good and works great. But this is not responsive means it does look equally good in mobile and desktop. I have tried to make the width 100%. It looks some good not always.

Comment: looks the same on my tablet to my desktop screen...but one option is get screen dimensions in javascript and adjust height and width of divs accordingly

Comment: @Dave, any exampl, will be helpfull

Comment: if no one answers after my new years party i will post a reply. i am on my mobile at moment its a pain writing answers on this thing

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would indeed be to set the width at +/- 100% for the wrapping div. Also instead of adding extra javascript perhaps mediaqueries are the way to go?

In .css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
```

//styles for small screen devices here

}

In .html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="a-stylesheet-for-smaller-screens.css" />
```

[More](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) [on the subject](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)